# Different definition of expectation value of quantum operator including density operaotor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

in QM lecture we are told that the average value of a quantum state in a mixed state is (when system is in state $|\psi_j\rangle$
with probabiity $p_j$ and given total probablitiy $\sum_j p_j=1$ is

$\langle \hat{A}\rangle=\sum_i p_i\langle \psi_i|\hat{A}|\psi_i\rangle$

which is something that is understood to me. then later the expectation value he define to be

$\langle \hat{A}\rangle=Trace(\hat{\rho}\hat{A})$

with define $\hat{\rho}=\sum_i p_i|\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|$. could someone point me on how to show both definition are same or how are they related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that for any operator $\hat O$ the trace is the sum of the diagonal components so that

$$Tr(\hat{O}) =  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \langle k|\hat{O}|k\rangle=O_{kk}$$

Also note that repeated indices are already *assumed to be summed over*, but I will keep your notation for clarity. We can now write

$$Tr(\hat{\rho}\hat{A})  = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i\langle k|\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|\hat{A}|k\rangle$$

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i\langle \psi_i|\hat{A}|k\rangle\langle k|\psi_i\rangle$$

and these step should be understandable.  Noting that $\sum|k\rangle\langle k|= \hat I$ the identity operator, you should be able to get the result you need. That is, this result for the trace will reduce to your first expression for the averaage value $\langle \hat A \rangle$.

The above equation certainly looks neater if you remove the $\sum$ symbols so that

$$Tr(\hat{\rho}\hat{A})  = p_i\langle k|\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|\hat{A}|k\rangle = p_i\langle \psi_i|\hat{A}|k\rangle\langle k|\psi_i\rangle$$

by remembering that repeated indices are summed over the space of states and the condition $|k\rangle\langle k|$ is the identity.